# Font errors with pdfLaTeX microtype package

Tags: ubuntu, latex, fonts, pdflatex, latexmk

On `Ubuntu 10.4LTS` I'm trying to use the [`microtype`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/microtype/) package in a [`memoir`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/) class of document, for example like this:

```
\usepackage[final,expansion=true]{microtype}
```

However, when I attempt to compile this (with `rubber`, `latexmk` or others) I get an  error like this:

> job.tex:72: Font
>   csnameendcsname=rm-lmr10+20 at 10.95pt
>   not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not
>   found.
>
> job.tex:72: leading text:
>   \parbox{5in}{Abstract!}
>
> job.tex:72: Font
>   csnameendcsname=rm-lmr10-20 at 10.95pt
>   not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not
>   found.
>
> job.tex:72: leading text:
>   \parbox{5in}{Abstract!}
>
> job.tex:80: Font
>   csnameendcsname=rm-lmr10+20 at 10.0pt
>   not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not
>   found.
>
> job.tex:80: leading text:
>   ...box{11cm}{\noindent{}All rights
>   reserved.}
>
> job.tex:80: Font
>   csnameendcsname=rm-lmr10-20 at 10.0pt
>   not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not
>   found.
>
> job.tex:80: leading text:
>   ...box{11cm}{\noindent{}All rights
>   reserved.}

Note, I'm leaving out lots of code that may be interacting, but the one active line that results in this error is the inclusion of the `microtype` package.

I'm using `\usepackage{lmodern}` and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, but when I leave those out the problem still exists, and the font names are correspondingly changed from `lmr10` to the default `cm10`.

This code works readily with TeXShop on Mac OS X, however it doesn't seem to work (readily) on Ubuntu. I just don't know enough about how to set up the fonts on Ubuntu to resolve this problem, and I'd be much obliged for input on how to resolve errors such as this.

Thank you.

Brian

Comment: Have you checked that the appropriate .tfm files are visible using kpsewhich?

Comment: @Charles: Great question. No, I haven't -- not sure how kpsewhich works. Running `kpsewhich -all ofm` and `kpsewhich -all .tfm` and other variations return nothing in all cases.

Comment: have you tried something like \usepackage{newcent} and see if the problem goes away?

Comment: kpsewhich doesn't return all files of a particular type, it tells you where a particular filename is.  E.g., on my setup, `kpsewhich rm-lmr10.tfm` returns a path, but `kpsewhich rm-lmr10+20.tfm` returns nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the microtype manual:

```
*! Font csnameendcsname=cmr10+20 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.*

Such an error message could occur if you are trying to employ font expansion
while creating DVI output. Remember, that automatic font expansion only works
when running pdfTEX in PDF mode. Although expansion is also possible in DVI
mode, it requires that all instances of the expanded fonts exist on your TEX
system.
```

Have you invoked pdftex with `pdflatex`?  If not, what happens when you do?

Comment: Thank you for the helpful reply. `pdflatex` does indeed create the pdf correctly, as you suggest it should. The problem therefore arises because I'm invoking tex via the `mklatex` and `rubber` commands - which evidently create DVI output as part of their tests. I guess my question becomes, then: how can one avoid the creation of DVI output in these build commands?

Comment: @Brian: write your own Makefile?

Answer (score 7):

In some cases, if you get an

```
 Metric (TFM) file not found
```

It can be solved with:

```
 sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-recommended
```

Comment: Named `texlive-collection-fontsrecommended` on fedora.